# Unapprove Bitbucket Pull Request reviewer approval

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

As a Pull Request owner, I want to remove approvals after I have made changes (commits) to the Pull Request.

I know there's the `Auto-unapprove` option:

> It removes reviewer approvals when new commits are pushed to a pull request's source branch.option

However, `Auto-unapprove` option is too aggressive. For example, I don't want commit squash to remove approvals from the PR.

How can I manually remove reviewer approval when there are *esssential* changes that I want them to review again?

Answer (score 0):

How to manually remove Pull Request approvals:

1. Edit the Pull Request (top right corner, `...` > `Edit`)
2. Remove the reviewers that have approved the PR but should review the PR again
3. Repeat the previous steps, but this time, re-add the reviewers that you just removed

Comment: Huh, so you can do it this way... You cannot do this in the PR ui cause they already have a status which is dumb IMO